# Show that the y-axis can be divided into infinitely many segments of equal non-Euclidean length.

Tags: geometry

Please see books.google.ca/books?isbn=0387290524 on pg 191 for more information.

Exercise 8.6.1: Show that the y-axis, and hence any non-euclidean line, can be divided into infinitely many segments of equal non-Euclidean length

My thoughts:

This definitely proves that this non-euclidean line can be extended in both directions, thus satisfying euclid's second axiom.

Note that 2$^n$i are equally spaced points, where n is all integers.

Comment: Can you add in the text exactly what metric is used?

Comment: isnt it |log(q/p)| for points ip and iq on y axis. I am assuming the logarithm is for any base.

Comment: I didn't copy the url (yet)..

Comment: Sounds to me like this $2^ni$ division should be an acceptable answer. What more do you require?